# Firestore create collection in console or add doc not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a collection on firestore within the console, but it doesn't let me move forward. It's asking to add the first document, but the save button is still disabled even tho I added an ID with Auth-ID as you can see in the picture below
[image]

I've red a lot of conversations on the web, and they all say we need to set an ID but nothing seems to work for me.

On another hand, I've tried to add a new document straight from my ReactJS app following the documentation example, but same thing here, there are no errors but nothing happens.

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

try {
   const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
       first: "Ada",
       last: "Lovelace",
       born: 1815
   });
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
 } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```

In the code above, docRef.id is `undefined` and nothing is added to the collection. The console prints the following:

```
Document written with ID:  undefined
```

My rules are set to "production" as follow:

```
  `rules_version = '2';
   service cloud.firestore {
       match /databases/{database}/documents {
       match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if false;
      }
    }
   }`
```

The documentation states that `Cloud Firestore creates collections and documents implicitly the first time you add data to the document.` So it should be there
thanks for the help

Comment: Did you go trough the similar SO Q&A? https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=firebase+start+a+collection+dialog+save+button+greyed+out

Comment: hey @RenaudTarnec thanks for your prompt reply. Actually none of the solutions seems to work. I've just updated the question with my rules config -> turning it into 'test' mode is not an option -> I need it to work in production as well

Comment: Yes that's strange: **From the console** the security rules should not be a problem, they are by-passed. **From the client** (ReactJS app), *it is normal*: you are forbidding any document creation with such rules. But you should see an error like "Missing or insufficient permissions.".

Comment: how can I enable creation for my reactjs app?  `allow read, write: if true;` the problem is that I don't have any JS error when trying to do so

Comment: `allow read, write: if true;` is indeed the way to check if the error comes from the security rules, since it allows anybody to write. You don't see any error, but don't you see the newly created doc in the collection?

Comment: PS to my above comment: `allow read, write: if true;` is interesting for debugging, but in most cases it shall not be kept as is in production, unless you want anybody to read and write from/to your Firestore DB.

Comment: by the way, I can't write to my db regardless this rule is set to true or false

Comment: It’s difficult to help you more… are you sure your are targeting the correct projet? You may contact the Firebase support.